# Why sendGoal is called with one parameter

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

sendGoal is defined with 4 parameters in simple_action_client.h but while using this API we call it with one parameter viz send Goal(goal). Why ?

Following is how it is defined in `simple_action_client.h`

```
void SimpleActionClient<ActionSpec>::sendGoal(const Goal& goal,
                                              SimpleDoneCallback     done_cb,
                                              SimpleActiveCallback   active_cb,
                                              SimpleFeedbackCallback feedback_cb)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274852/why-sendgoal-is-called-with-one-parameter/) by [Raj](https://answers.ros.org/users/32483/raj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-11-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In `simple_action_client.h` it's defined like this:

```
void sendGoal(const Goal& goal,
                SimpleDoneCallback     done_cb     = SimpleDoneCallback(),
                SimpleActiveCallback   active_cb   = SimpleActiveCallback(),
                SimpleFeedbackCallback feedback_cb = SimpleFeedbackCallback());
```

In C++ you can specify default function argument value with `=` sign. It's an optional value and therefore doesn't need to be present while calling that function. If you don't specify one it will take the default value (e.g. `SimpleDoneCallback()`).

---

Originally posted by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) with karma: 826 on 2017-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Raj](https://answers.ros.org/users/32483/raj/) on 2017-11-04**:
Got it. Thank you

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2017-11-06**:
@Raj please accept the answer above with the checkmark to the left so others know it's resolved.

**Comment by [Raj](https://answers.ros.org/users/32483/raj/) on 2017-11-06**:
@tfoote: I guess I did it before. Sorry if I missed it.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2017-11-06**:
@Raj it's still not checked. Click on the checkmark itself (it will turn green) to indicate that it's resolved.

**Comment by [Raj](https://answers.ros.org/users/32483/raj/) on 2017-11-06**:
@tfoote I did and it's showing green to me.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2017-11-07**:
Are you sure you got the check mark and not the upvote arrow? If you mouse over it should say "mark this answer as correct"

**Comment by [Raj](https://answers.ros.org/users/32483/raj/) on 2017-11-07**:
@tfoote Oh My bad. Sorry as  I am new user.  I hope now I did it correctly

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2017-11-07**:
No worries, there's always a learning curve for new interfaces. I'm glad you got your question answered quickly.

**Comment by [Raj](https://answers.ros.org/users/32483/raj/) on 2017-11-07**:
What does the up arrow near comments mean ?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2017-11-07**:
It's an upvote to vote for one answer versus another. It's useful if there are many answers to a question and you find one useful you can upvote it even if you weren't the person who asked it.